# Does a bankruptcy cancel out capital losses? (US)

Tags: income-tax, capital-gains-tax, irs, bankruptcy

If I filed for chapter 7 bankruptcy does the amount of the debt discharged in bankruptcy cancel the prior capital losses i had so that I am unable to use those losses to cancel capital gains?  Are there any exceptions?

Comment: For clarification: Are you asking about personal or corporate bankruptcy? And given that you tagged it IRS, this _is_ in the US, right?

Comment: Yes.  The US.  And chapter 7, personal.